# What license to use while putting papers on the Arxiv?

Tags: publications, arxiv, open-access, license, creative-commons

I am new to this and not sure what to make of all the options available. I am interested in putting a machine-learning-related preprint, which will potentially be submitted to places like NIPS/ICLR/ICML in the future.

- arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license to distribute this article (Minimal rights required by arXiv.org)
- Creative Commons Attribution license (CC BY 4.0)
- Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license (CC BY-SA 4.0)
- Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-ShareAlike license (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0)
- Creative Commons Public Domain Declaration (CC0 1.0)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the right license that you can always safely pick (assuming you can submit to arXiv at all):

> arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license to distribute this article (Minimal rights required by arXiv.org)

Comment: To add to this, you can always check [SHERPA/RoMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/index.php) to see the policies of the target venues - some venues may not accept submissions that have previously been published on ArXiv, and choosing anything but the license mentioned in this answer will disqualify you from submitting to most venues that do not allow Open Access publishing with Creative Commons licenses.

Comment: I agree with Jukka Suomela. If you intend to submit your paper to a journal later, you will probably need to assign your copyright to the journal publisher. That could be a problem if you've already made the work available on a Creative Commons licence.

Comment: I have made my work available on the arXiv under CC0, then when the publisher turned up with copyright transfer in hand, after the academic editors had accepted the paper, I told them I couldn't sign it, and both times they have backed down and let me sign something consistent with the license on the arXiv.

Comment: I would also change what you wrote to "this is the license you can always safely pick". I see more and more papers appearing on the arXiv with CC licenses, so claiming the default license is the "right" one is not a good message.

Comment: [You don't _have to_ sign over copyright](http://www.sciencecommons.org/resources/faq/authorsaddendum). Also, you will want to pick a less restrictive license if you want your work to have maximum impact, such as CC BY.

Comment: It is the license you can always safely pick, but not the best one in terms of making your work widely available.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, is this the CC 0 license? Could you please elaborate a bit more? I see that many authors choose the CC BY-NC-ND.

Comment: This answer do not explain anything about why this license would be better over another. It largely depends on the context and not providing any detail about the "why" is misleading.